# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't see second monitor daisy chained through displayport

Tags: multiple-monitors, radeon, 16.04, displayport

I have two Dell U2414H monitors connected in chain to AMD R7 250X. Today I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and in settings I see only one monitor while screen is duplicated on second monitor.

Is there a way to make both monitors work in this config?

Answer (score 0):

It a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/1509997) which has been reported.

Answer (score -1):

The Daisy Chain require Intel HD Graphics. Details in [Dell's KB](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN295251/how-to-configure-u2415-monitor-daisy-chaining-on-intel-hd-graphics?lang=EN).